# My model changes the size when the animation is started

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

When the game starts, the animation starts with it, how do I make it so that the animation will not change the size of my model.

I tried adding the animation which ended up being successful but the animation changed the size of my model as well as the position, I was not expecting it to be like that, I did fix the issue with the position though.